# Unsolved problem about congruent conics

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

In the book *Tomorrow's Math: Unsolved Problems for the Amateur* by C. S. Ogilvy I read:

> "A very slippery question in plane analytic geometry is, if the six conics determined by each five of a set of six points are congruent, must they coincide? Stated in 1943, the problem is still unsolved despite having received considerable attention"

Is it still unsolved?